# Is it possible to use a Symbian based Nokia phone as a webcam via USB?

Tags: webcam, phone, nokia

I have a Nokia E6 with Symbian Belle and a PC running Ubuntu 12.04.

Is it possible to use a Symbian based Nokia phone as a webcam via USB?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible. You will have to install SmartCam. 
SmartCam - Smart Phone Web Camera - Turns a camera phone (S60, WinMo6.x, Android, Samsung Bada) with bluetooth or WiFi into a handy webcam ready to use with your PC. You can get [SmartCam here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/smartcam/files/).

Comment: do we have to install the client on the phone first?

Comment: there is no option to use connect my phone via usb

Comment: Which phone are you using? This works for Nokia E6

Comment: I'm using Nokia 6700 slide. Symbian S60 v3 runs on it. There is only bluetooth and wifi option to connect in smartcam.

Comment: And I got some errors when I was installing this SmartCam on my Ubuntu 13.04